# Can I use a function as a criteria in SUMIF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns: one contains numbers, the other contains dates. I want to add all the number from the first column for which the date is, for example, in **March**.

I know that I can add a new column which will contain `=MONTH()` and then use it as a *criteria range* in `SUMIF`.

Is there a way to do it just using the two columns?

Comment: you can use something like this: `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A2:A10)=3)*(B2:B10))`

Comment: I tested it and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done without helper column with months listed. Instead try SUMPRODUCT() or SUM(), you can try this with ctrl+shift+enter:

`=SUM((MONTH(A1:A15)=3)*B1:B15)`